# Are Kafka Streams State Stores a valid solution for stateful applications dealing with high volumes of keys and data?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to determine whether Kafka Streams state stores are a good fit for this problem:

- A topic will be receiving data that will have over 20000 different keys.
- For every key from the stream I need to keep 12 entries in a state store, one per month of the year, e.g. key 1:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|STATE STORE KEY (key + year-month) | STATE STORE VALUE|
--------------------------------------------------------
|              1-2020-02            |       100.19     |
|              1-2020-01            |       12.0       |
|              1-2019-12            |       19.0       |
|                 ...               |       ...        |
|              1-2019-03            |       1.0        |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

With 20k keys I would be keeping 240k key-value pairs in the state store. I know I can scale horizontally the Kafka Streams applications to distribute the information, but:

- Is Kafka a good fit for this problem?
- How can I determine the amount of RAM memory needed per Kafka Streams instance?
- How can I determine the amount of disk space needed for RocksDB per Kafka Streams instance?
- Any guidelines to determine a good number of replicas to deal with this load?

**UPDATE**

Just a few clarifications:

1. I will use Interactive queries to access info by key, which as seen above consists of stream-key+month.
2. I am indeed processing data. The value associated to each key results from aggregating data every month: data arrives continuously during the day and is stored as a monthly average. I need to keep the last 12 months aggregation.
3. I think replicas are also a factor in load since Kafka distributes the ids among them, so all the keys/values from the state stores are also distributed among them, thus reducing the memory requirements per instance, am I right?

Comment: What's wrong with Redis or other databases?

Comment: You can configure how much memory RocksDB will use. This guide might help: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Kafka a good fit for this problem?

It'll work for storage, however, you've not mentioned the query access needed.

> How can I determine the amount of RAM memory needed per Kafka Streams instance? How can I determine the amount of disk space needed for RocksDB per Kafka Streams instance?

Sounds like you're just storing data, not really processing it, and the persistent state stores are off heap, so start at default heap sizes and monitor it...

Regarding storage, RocksDB is only the default option - you can implement a custom state store provider. But you can determine the UTF8 size of your strings and the number of bytes in a double to get a rough idea of size.

> Any guidelines to determine a good number of replicas to deal with this load?

Replicas are a factor in availability, not necessarily load... Start with 3-5 replicas

Comment: Okay, interactive queries is obviously needed, but that doesn't answer if you're accessing multiple keys at once, all keys, or just one at a time. Kafka can store years of data,assuming you monitor disk usage appropriately, like any other server. Replication can cause load, sure, but it's not the main driving factor because every other topic is hopefully replicated as well.

Comment: It’s likely I would need to get the yearly results, so 12 keys. The kstreams applications are running on Kubernetes and given that rocksdb is, as you pointed out, in disk not in memory, is the default container storage enough or does it need to be configured in some way?

Comment: You'd have to use PVC, so you wouldn't be using "default container storage"

Comment: Mmm in my environment, GKE, that is a problem since the pvc can only be mounted as ReadWriteOnce. That is to say all replicas would share a volumen on which all of them cannot write. Since the rocksdb data doesn’t need to be persistent  (it will be recreated by the change log topic, I was expecting to rely on the default container disk space...